# ¿Cómo asignar un evento a un mismo botón? por ejemplo, para editar y eliminar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día a todos, tengo la siguiente duda quisiera que me orientaran que investigar para hacer lo siguiente.
Tengo una función que me dibuja las tareas que se necesitan hacer, tiene el botón de editar y eliminar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Main row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Left col -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- TO DO List -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="ion ion-clipboard"></i>
              <h3 class="box-title">To Do List</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <!-- See dist/js/pages/dashboard.js to activate the todoList plugin -->
              <ul class="todo-list">
                <li>              
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">                
                  <span class="text">Design a nice theme</span>                
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Make the theme responsive</span>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>                  
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Check your messages and notifications</span>                  
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>                  
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer clearfix no-border">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>        
      </div>
      <!-- /.row (main row) -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
<!-- scripts -->
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que dibujó en php con un foreach es lo siguiente, en cada iteración me dibuja el botón de editar y eliminar. Yo directamente ponía el evento onclick en el botón pasándole el parámetro del `id` de la tarea, y realmente funciona bien. pero me dicen que es mala práctica, que no se debe hacer así

```
<?php foreach (tareas::lista_tareas() as $tarea): ?>
  <li id = "<?=$tarea->id?>">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text"><?=$tarea->tarea ?></span>
    <div class="tools">
      <i value = "<?=$tarea->id?>" onclick="editar(this.value);" class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i value = "<?=$tarea->id?>" onclick="eliminar(this.value);" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Entonces, de qué otra manera se le puede asignar el evento de editar o eliminar al botón que no sea directamente en el html?
Tomando en cuenta que por cada iteración se repetirá el mismo botón en cada `<li></li>`
ya lo intente con jquery pero como el botón tiene el mismo nombre, solo me funciona el primer botón los demás no hacen nada, por lo que me resulta del foreach es algo así,
la parte de `fa-edit` y `fa-trash-o` se repiten siempre.

```
  <li id = "<?=$tarea->id?>">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="text"><?=$tarea->tarea ?></span>
    <div class="tools">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Hola @huichochitlan. En tu código html los elementos `li` carecen de `id` debes asignarles tal atributo de modo explícito para poder usar referencias fáciles a ellos en la iteración.

Comment: si tienen id, se lo asigno de la siguiente manera  <li id = "<?=$tarea->id?>">

Comment: Lo siento. Revisé el html arriba y no noté la asignación que se hace en el snipet siguiente. Acabo de ver que abajo te ofrecen una respuesta totalmente funcional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes seleccionar el elemento con `jQuery` mediante su clase, después le agregamos la función `click` y obtenemos el valor con `.attr`. Espero te sirva, cualquier duda hazla saber. :)

```js
let btn_edit = $('.fa-edit');

btn_edit.click(function(){
          console.log($(this).attr('value')); 
    })

let btn_delete= $('.fa-trash-o');

    btn_delete.click(function(){
          console.log($(this).attr('value')); 
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i value = "1"  class="fa fa-edit">edita</i>
<i value = "2"  class="fa fa-trash-o">elimina</i>
<i value = "3"  class="fa fa-edit">edita</i>
<i value = "4"  class="fa fa-trash-o">elimina</i>
<i value = "5"  class="fa fa-edit">edita</i>
<i value = "6"  class="fa fa-trash-o">elimina</i>
```

Comment: lo voy a implementar, parece que es lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Me parece perfecto, no olvides que si fue de utilidad marcarla como aceptada, así usuarios que tengan el mismo problema sabrán cuál fue la solución. Excelente día. :D

Comment: Si me sirvio pero utilisé javascript nativo, porque lo que hago es de una petición ajax y posteriormente dibujar el html que me retorna un archivo php y jquery no lo reconoce, pero javascript si reconoce el html que me retorna la petición ajax

Comment: De hecho en jQuery es mucho más fácil usar AJAX pero lo importante es que funcione, buen día compañero. :D